# iphone development: how to check if an object located on the phone's screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, scrollview

In my app I have a scrollview which has some objects like an imageview, a button etc. and my scrollview has a huge content so I need to scroll vertically or horizontally to explore it. My question is how can I check if an object is located at a visible position on the phone's screen?

Edit : I want to detect if the image is completely in the scrollView's frame or not. however `CGRectIntersectsRect(bottomScroller.bounds, selectImage_1.frame)` returns true even if there is a small intersection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare your object's  (imageview, a button etc.) frame with the `scrollView.bounds`:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(scrollView.bounds, object.frame)) ...
```

EDIT:

If you want to ensure that the object is fully displayed, then calculate the intersection and compare it to the object's frame:

```
CGRectEqualToRect(
      CGRectIntersection(scrollView.bounds, object.frame),
      object.frame);
```

although you might found an optimized way to do that check.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the problem is I want to detect if the image is completely in the scrollView's frame or not. however it returns true even if there is a small intersection.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the other answers, you'll want to use `CGRectIntersectsRect` as this will output only when your object is in intersection with the visible frame of the scroll view. However, in order to make this more complete, you should use `UIScrollViewDelegate's` method `scrollViewDidScroll` which will allow you to more or less ask for the intersection when ever scrolling occurs. Here's an example:

.h

```
<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

.m

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(mySubView.frame, scrollView.bounds)) {
        CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(mySubView.frame, scrollView.bounds);
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(intersection));
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Then using `CGRectIntersectsRect` you can ask for the specific intersection and at this point all you have to do to make this depended on your needs is write something like `if(intersect.x > y)//do something`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the problem is I want to detect if the image is completely in the scrollView's frame or not. however it returns true even if there is a small intersection.